# Laravel Auth get disconnected when i try post file

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, axios

Hello i'm using Laravel 5.5 and trying to upload a file with vuejs and axios post,
when i upload the file a function is fired but at the server the auth is disconnected don't know why
i've disabled the VerifyCsrfToken because break all my previous axios posts 
that's my code at Vuejs :

```
    // update profile picture
    uploadProfilePicture(){
      let file = event.target.files
      let form = new FormData();
      form.append('file',file[0]);
      axios.post('update-picture',form)
      .then((response)=>console.log(responsea.data))
      .catch((error)=>console.log(error.response.data))

    },
```

that's my code at server

```
    // update photo profile
public function updatePicture(Request $request)
{

    $file = $request->file;

    $res = Storage::disk('localLinked')->put('default/user/profile',$file);

    $picture = \App\Picture::create([
        'link'=>$res
    ]);

    Auth::user()->profilePicture()->delete();

    Auth::user()->update([
        'idProfilePicture'=>$picture->id
    ]);
    dd('done');

}
```

the error is that Auth::user() always null 
please help i'm stack here 
Thanks

Comment: Obvious question - are you really logged in?

Comment: yes i checked the return Auth::user()
in other functions and returns true
but if i tired to post file 
then it's logged out !

Comment: Is your web middleware applied on that route?